# My Django if statement do not work correctly

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.8

I have created a admin panel on the frontend and would like to show different layouts if they are on the index.html or if they are on pages after /admin e.g:

```
/admin/dashboard
/admin/posts
/admin/media
```

**My if statement:**

```
{% if request.path == "/admin" %}
```

It doesn't work for some reason and I can't figure out why. This is an example of the whole if:

```
<div class="row">

{% if request.path == "/admin" %}
<div class="col-md-full">
{% else %}
<div class="col-md-7 left">
  {% block main %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if request.path == "/admin" %}
{% trans "Empty" %}
{% else %}
<div class="col-md-3 right">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
    {% block right_panel %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}

</div>
```

Comment: try adding a slash at the end `== "/admin/"`

Comment: @Pynchia: It's the same result when adding a slash at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about?

```
{% if '/admin/' in request.path %}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you @doniyor!